# Plotting a dynamic C5.0 decision tree in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny application to let users choose dependent / independent variables on demand then perform C5.0 to generate summary and a tree plot. However, there was error message when generating the plot. Does anyone know the solution? Kindly find the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Plotting Decision Tree'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3('iris data'),
      uiOutput('choose_y'),
      uiOutput('choose_x'),
      actionButton('c50', label = 'Generate C5.0 summary and plot')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput('tree_summary'),
      plotOutput('tree_plot_c50')
    )
  )
)

# server.R
library(shiny)
library(C50)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$choose_y <- renderUI({
    is_factor <- sapply(iris, FUN = is.factor)
    y_choices <- names(iris)[is_factor]
    selectInput('choose_y', label = 'Choose Target Variable', choices = y_choices)
  })

  output$choose_x <- renderUI({
    x_choices <- names(iris)[!names(iris) %in% input$choose_y]
    checkboxGroupInput('choose_x', label = 'Choose Predictors', choices = x_choices)
  })

  observeEvent(input$c50, {
    c50_fit <- C5.0(as.formula(paste(isolate(input$choose_y), '~', paste(isolate(input$choose_x), collapse = '+'))), data = iris)
    output$tree_summary <- renderPrint(summary(c50_fit))
    output$tree_plot_c50 <- renderPlot({
      plot(c50_fit)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `server.R` try

```
function(input, output) {
  output$choose_y <- renderUI({
    is_factor <- sapply(iris, FUN = is.factor)
    y_choices <- names(iris)[is_factor]
    selectInput('choose_y', label = 'Choose Target Variable', choices = y_choices)
  })

  output$choose_x <- renderUI({
    x_choices <- names(iris)[!names(iris) %in% input$choose_y]
    checkboxGroupInput('choose_x', label = 'Choose Predictors', choices = x_choices)
  })

  observeEvent(input$c50, {
    form <- paste(isolate(input$choose_y), '~', paste(isolate(input$choose_x), collapse = '+'))
    c50_fit <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("C5.0(%s, data = iris)", form)))
    output$tree_summary <- renderPrint(summary(c50_fit))
    output$tree_plot_c50 <- renderPlot({
      plot(c50_fit)
    })
  })
}
```

---

*Explanation.* The `plot` method appears to be looking for the terms specified in the `call` element of the returned value from `C5.0()`, and throws an error when they are not found.  In your case, this refers to the `input` object. The workaround is to call `C5.0()` with the formula fully specified (e.g. `Species ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Width`) through the `eval(parse(text = ...))` construction.

Comment: Awesome solution, and so is the explanation! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Additional question: what if my iris data is a reactiveValues object? Say: `react_vals <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)`   `react_vals$data <- iris`, the `plot` method fails once I transformed `iris` to a reactiveValues object.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a question with a one-liner solution, you should open a new question with a minimal example.

Comment: No problem, I shall open a new question!

Comment: [new question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633863/plotting-dynamic-c5-0-decision-tree-in-shiny-with-reactivevalues)

Comment: Just saw it.  I think you should write a couple of lines to explain the background because other users may not bother to click through to read this question.  Some users may give downvotes for questions that are not well described.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and kindness for a newbie.